# how to go to the certain column or part of the line using "sed" command?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, command

```
Permissions   links  Owner  Group  Size   Date        Time    Directory or file
-rwxr--r--     1     User1  root    26    2012-04-12  19:51    MyFile.txt
drwxrwxr-x     3     User2  csstf  4096   2012-03-15  00:12     MyDir
```

Note that each space is a tab space.  
I need to go to the size column. How can I do that using `sed` command. Because I cannot continue my work due to that. I don't know how to split and take certain part of the line using `sed` command.

Comment: You probably don't have to use ls; GNU find has a printf option, so you could print out just the fields you want in an order which can be parsed more easily in whatever too you prefer. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "go to the size column"? Are you talking about cursor positioning, or extracting that columns data, or something else?

Comment: @twalberg for example, i need to get the number of files with execute permission for the owner.

Comment: @codeSlayer789 It seems to me that information would be in the "Permissions" column, not the "Size" column. Your comment does not add any clarity to your question. Consider rewording the question to be specific about what you want, along with example input and output, and show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk suites it better:

```
awk -F'\t' '{print $5}' file
```

**Using sed:**

```
sed -r 's/^([^\t]+\t){4}([^\t]+).*$/\2/' file
Size
26
4096
```

Comment: Since tab and space is default for `awk` this should be sufficient: `awk '{print $5}' file`

Comment: how to use `sed` for that @anubhava

Comment: I've had problems on Solaris when not leaving a space between the `-F` and the split character.

Comment: @Jotne I need to use `sed` to find and display the largest size 3 file and also total number of files with execute permission for the owner.

Comment: @codeSlayer789: Provided a sed version but my preference is awk